# Understanding responsible callers in Instruments Results for Alloc

Tags: ios, instruments

I am using instruments to pindown on what is consuming more memory. I always get the Living bytes and overall bytes to be same. I believe not much deallocation has happened in my code. And this is a bad sign.

When I go and find the responsible caller and track down what it is, I could not find it. The responsible callers are _dydldstart and NSStringFromClass.

Is this behaviour normal ? How can check the exact responsible caller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I always get the Living bytes and overall bytes to be same".

I had this problem  only because I was setting up NSZombieEnabled as environment variables when I was testing my App in Instruments. After disabling that variable, the problem had gone.

NSZombieEnabled I think does not let any variables to be released.

I am not sure if removing NSZombieEnabled solved the probelm.

I was actually using Allocations in two different ways. Only when used with Leaks Tool, I had the problem.

Another question of Mine is an answer to this question:

[Ambiguities in using Instruments for iOS Development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357071/ambiguities-in-using-instruments-for-ios-development)

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the Living Bytes and Overall Bytes columns being the same is most likely that Instruments is tracking only active allocations. If you want Instruments to track everything, click the Info button next to the Allocations instrument in the instrument list and deselect the Only track active allocations checkbox.

Opening the extended detail view shows the call stack for your memory allocations, which will make it easier to find the exact responsible caller. Choose View > Extended Detail to open the extended detail view.

The call tree view can also help you determine where you are allocating memory in your code. Use the jump bar to switch to the call tree view.